# add all-subdirectories wildcard to $PATH environment variable (bash)

Tags: python, bash

Here's my directory structure (`creddump/` is a program I downloaded directly from [github](https://github.com/moyix/creddump) that is not supported by any package manager):

```
/usr/local/bin/
    ---> creddump/
        ---> pwdump.py (imports from framework)
        ---> framework/
            ---> types.py
        ---> lsadump.py
    ---> another_program/
        ---> x.py
```

I'd like to be able to run `pwdump.py` and `x.py` simply by typing `pwdump.py` and `x.py`, not their full paths. So, I added their paths to my `$PATH` environment variable by adding it to the beginning of this line in the `~/.bashrc` file like this:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin/creddump/:/usr/local/bin/another_program/:~/.local/bin:/snap/bin:/usr/sandbox/:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/usr/share/games:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:$PATH
```

That's great, but I don't want to manually add another line to `$PATH` every time I want to download another program. I did some digging and found out that bash supports wildcard expansion. I uncommented this line in `~/.bashrc`: `shopt -s globstar` and I added `/usr/local/bin/**/:` to the beginning of the `export PATH` line above. After, I did `source ~/.bashrc` and/or I restarted the terminal during my various attempts. But, it didn't work;

```
bash: pwdump.py: command not found
```

I also tried adding it to the middle and end, but nothing worked.
I know this should be able to work because I've gotten it to work before I upgraded my Parrot Security OS system from 4.10 to 4.11. I've even tried adding the `export PATH` line to `~/.profile` as well.

Any ideas on how to fix this? Thank you so much!

Comment: did u open a new bash terminal once u saved the change in .bashrc?

Comment: @harshvchawla yes, I edited my question. thanks

Comment: By definition of "install", the act of installing a program makes it available for execution in your environment.   If you need to add it to your PATH after the fact, then you haven't installed the program; you've merely copied a bunch of files onto your filesystem.

Comment: Globs `*` does not expand on assignment afaik.

Comment: ok, and can u run ./pwdump.py on its own? whether it has execute permission (chmod +x filename)

Comment: @WilliamPursell that makes sense, I've edited my wording.

Comment: @harshvchawla yes, I can do that once I've used `cd` to get into the `/usr/local/bin/creddump/` directory

Comment: @Jetchisel I've read that somewhere, but that can't be true bc it worked before on my system before the upgrade.

Comment: @tommy2111111111, that's not a good upgrade...

Comment: This should just print the new `PATH` but not sure if it can export it, I haven't done anything like what you're asking for.  `find /usr/local/bin/ -type f -name '*.py' -exec bash -c 'new_path=$(IFS=':'; printf '%s' "${*%/*}"); echo PATH="$PATH:${new_path}"' _ {} +`

Comment: Or just add that in your `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.profile` ?

Answer (score 5):

For whom tommy2111111111's incredibly simple solution (for which I can't find an explanation) doesn't work, here's an alternative in accordance with documentation:

```
d=(/usr/local/bin/**/)
PATH="${d[*]/%\//:}"$PATH
```

Comment: tommy2111111111 is now user15365111.

Comment: Nice! Now my `~/.local/programs/*/bin` auto expands into path

Answer (score 1):

so when I experiment on my own system, this is how I see the path variable once I added the globstar pattern: `...:./path1:./**/` - which is not reading all the paths (perhaps pattern matching is not part of PATH, dont know)

- If you are not creating new subdirectories all the time and just want "all subdirectories that currently exist to PATH variable", then a for loop to upgrade your PATH variable would suffice (like is mentioned here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17715/how-can-i-set-all-subdirectories-of-a-directory-into-path/17856#17856)
- but if you want to achieve objective "add all future subdirectories to my PATH"; then in that same answer link, there is a mention of http://www.gnu.org/software/stow/ which seems like its solving your usecase

Comment: As a former Stow user, I've jumped ship to Nix; you might find it worth looking at.

Answer (score 1):

OMG!!! I fixed it! Instead of adding `/usr/local/bin/**/`, I just did `/usr/local/bin/**` without the ending `/`. I also had to edit the `~/.bashrc` file with `sudo nano ~/.bashrc`. Thank you to everyone else who responded; your solutions work perfectly for me, but I was just looking for a much simpler solution.

Comment: I have a hard time believing that this works. $PATH then contains the unexpanded `/usr/local/bin/**`, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this. Just name the file `file.txt`

```
add_path() {
  declare -a new_path
  local IFS=:
  mapfile -t new_path < <(find /usr/local/bin/ -type f -name '*.py')
  NEW_PATH=${new_path[*]%/*}
  export PATH="$PATH:$NEW_PATH"
}

add_path
```

Just source that file.

```
source ./file.txt
```

Then try to execute your python scripts without the absolute paths.

Comment: `NEW_PATH=$(IFS=':'; printf '%s' "${new_path[*]}")` is massively overcomplicated. Why the command substitution? Why the printf at all?

Comment: `IFS=:; NEW_PATH=${new_path[*]}`  does everything needed, as long as you're in a function with `local IFS` run previously to prevent the change from escaping.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thank you for that wonderful comment, change accordingly.